# How to understand a proposition of subgradient

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

The question is from the following:

> Convex Optimization Algorithm (p.512)----- Prof. Bertsekas

Let $f: R^n \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$ be a proper convex function. For every $x \in \text{ri}(\text{dom}(f)) $,

$$\partial f(x) = S^{\perp}+G$$

Notation:
1. $\partial f(x)$ is the set of all subgradients of $f$ at $x$.
2. $S$:  the subspace that is parallel to the affine hull of dom$(f).$
3. $G$ is a nonempty convex and compact set.
4. $\text{ri}()$: relative interior of (a set)

I have no ideat of what this proposition is talking about. How to prove it?

Comment: Is G linked with S or with the function f ?

Comment: The book does not say more about $G$. What I am confused here is that: It is possible there is only one vector (if considering the differentiable part) representing he subgradient. How could it be the sum of two. Moreover, should the summation be direct sum?

Comment: This result just says that on the relative interior of the domain the values of the subdifferential are non-empty compact convex up to the added orthogonal of the affine hull of the domain. This is a structure result.

Comment: If the domain has nonempty interior, then $S^\perp=\{0\}$, the trivial subspace. The sum in the equation is just a Minkowski sum.

Comment: So for example: $f(x) = ||x||_1$ and $\text{dom}f \in R^2$ and $x \in R^2$. Then in this case, $S^{\perp} = \{0\}, \forall x \in R^2$ . True?